# JDeveloper 11g and Spring

Tags: jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

I new to Jdeveloper. I want to build a sample Spring web app.
In making a new application, I chose "Java EE Web Application" and JDev made the application and two projects. I did not see how to add Spring.
Should Spring show up as one of the "Project Technologies" from which to choose?

Comment: Why do you think it should? Spring has nothing to do with JavaEE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of JDeveloper are you using? Earlier versions require you to download the Spring Extension.
Basic instructions here:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jdev/htdocs/partners/addins/exchange/spring/spring-extension.html
http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jdev/howtos/1013/SpringwithJDev/index.html